# Writing a bash script to execute/automate install of drivers

Tags: drivers, bash, automation

i'm trying to write a script to automate the install of TV card drivers (for some reason i have to re-install after each ubuntu update).

Would this work? I've tried it but it doesn't look like it's doing anything.....

```
#/!bin/bash
# script to reinstall TV card drivers...

function install() {

wget http://www.tbsdtv.com/download/document/common/tbs-linux-drivers_v140707.zip
mkdir driver
mv tbs-linux-drivers_v140707.zip ./driver/
cd driver/
tar xjvf linux-tbs-drivers.tar.bz2
cd linux-tbs-drivers/
./v4l/tbs-x86_r3.sh
sudo make
sudo make install
shutdown -r now

}
```

Comment: Did you got any error?

Comment: no errors of any kind when i do ./SetupTVDrivers

Comment: You forgot to call your function `install` at the end of or script. But, better to not use any function, just the code inside of it.

Comment: Also you have downloaded .zip file when you extract .tar.bz2 file.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. Not every update, but every kernel update, that is why ubuntu uses DKMS for automatic compilation of modules for new kernels.
2. As @Radu Rădeanu wrote you didn't call install function.
3. To unpack archive in a script use `tar xf archivename`
4. use `make && sudo make install && sudo shutdown -r now`, because if `make` fails your script will still try to install those drivers and restart system. It is also a good idea to use `make clean` before compiling.
5. You don't have to download drivers every time, just put them in `/usr/local/src/`

Comment: Make shouldn't need sudo, only make install should. Also, put local stuff in /usr/local.

Comment: Are drivers considered local stuff? Kernel and kernel modules are usually put in /usr/src, even by module-assistant.

Comment: not drivers per se, but stuff that the user is downloading and adding. /usr/local is meant for that sort of thing, and is in general off-limits to packages in the repository, so no package will interfere. The `make install` of course will still go to /usr.

Comment: Good point, never had this sort of problem because I usually use /root/src, it makes system migration go smoother. All I need is to backup /root/ folder.